# Generate summary of an url like facebook in Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook

Is there any gem in ruby to generate a summary of an url similar to what facebook does when you post a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I'm aware of, but it should't be too hard to roll your own. In the simplest case you can just `require 'open-uri'` and then use the `open` method to retrieve the contents of the site, or go for one of the HTTP libraries.

Once you got the document, all you have to do is use something like Nokogori or Hpricot to get the title, first paragraph of text and an image and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a thumbnail isn't a straightforward task. The page has to be rendered, the window captured, shrunk down, then stored or returned. While it would be possible for a gem to do it, there would be significant overhead.

There are websites that can create the thumbnails, then you can reference the image:

- [Websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/)
- [Webthumb](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home)
- [ShrinkTheWeb](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/)
- [iWEBTOOL](http://thumbnails.iwebtool.com/)

I haven't tried them, but there's a good page discussing the first two on [The Accidental Technologist](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/programmatically-creating-website-thumbnails/).

If you need some text from the page, its simple to grab some, but making it be sensible is a different problem:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
page_text = doc.text
print page_text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').squeeze(' ')[0..99]
# >> IANA — Example domains Domains Numbers Protocols About IANA Example Domains As described in RFC 2606
```